# Cardinality of set of all orthogonal matrices over $\Bbb Z$

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

Let $S$ be the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices over $\Bbb Z$ such that the product $AA^t=I$. Then find $|S|$?

Taking $A=$\begin{bmatrix} a & b &c \\d & e& f\\g & h & i\end{bmatrix} we get $3$ relations $a^2+b^2+c^2=1;d^2+e^2+f^2=1;g^2+h^2+i^2=1;$

How should I count from here?

Comment: The rows also have to be orthogonal, that is, their scalar products need to be zero. For your question, think about how big $a^2$, $b^2$ and $c^2$ can be for their sum to be only $1$. Remember that squares are always nonnegative.

Comment: $a=1,-1$ and same for all @David

Comment: Any trouble with $0$?

Comment: You're saying $a$, $b$, $c$ should all be $\pm 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From given conditions we find that rows of the matrix are from the following  $$[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[-1,0,0],[]0,-1,0],[0,0,-1].$$

Now first row has any $6$ possibilities then second one as 4 and third one as 2. So total possibilities are $48.$

Comment: another way to say it is $2^3 3!$, in general $2^n n!$

Comment: yes its right...

Comment: Thanks @neela; Its pretty clear now